# one query from multiple APIs

Tags: javascript, api, web-applications

Is it possible to make one query from API's from different sources?  ie,

In traditional web development If I have the following modules:

- Clients:  clientID, clientName
- Orders: ordersID, clientID

I would create 2 tables in ONE database and foreign keys with joins and make my query.

What I would like to do is instead of ONE database to create 2 databases, one for each module (this way I can expand each module as it's own entity easier) and "tie" the 2 databases through APIs.

So, I would still use "foreign keys" (ie, clientID in the Orders table) to "tie" clients and orders, but I could not "join" them because they are not in the same database.

So, in my interface I would have a:

- client API like http:mysite.com/showallClientsAPI
- OrdersAPI like http:mysite.com/showallOrdersAPI

How would I do a query (or is it possible) though APIs between the modules to get this response:

- SaleA

  - clientName 1
  - clientName 2
  - etc
- SaleB

  - clientName 1
  - clientName 3

I could show all Orders(http://mysite.com/showSalesAPI) that have clientID=1 but that would give me a json response with the **clientID** and not the **clientName**.

Does that make sense?

(you might ask why I would want to do this.  this is part of a multi module application that it would make sense to keep the modules separate than as part of a huge database, for future development or interaction with other applications)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of splitting out databases and putting them behind services, but I think it should be done with care.  If you are going to do joins constantly between clients and orders, why make them communicate via services?

Some thoughts:

- Maybe replicate data from server to server so the client/order queries can happen quickly. That way each server is still authoritative.
- You can definitely join the entities in code of course.  You could write wrappers that sit on top of each API and then do something like this (C#):

```
List clientNames = new List();
var orders = OrderService.GetOrders();

foreach (var order in orders)
{
   var client = ClientService.GetClient(order.ClientId);
   clientNames.Add(client.FirstName + " " + client.LastName);
}
```

(Note: This is inefficient, you might want to pass a list of client IDs)

Something like the above would call two services in a simple way and then "join" them in your application.  If that feels like too much work, then consider replication! =)

- Use something like Mule (http://www.mulesoft.org/) to handle the integration of services.  With Mule you can create endpoints to REST services (or any HTTP web service) and then join them together into one "message".
- No matter what you do, if you split the data across servers, you are going to pay a little higher price for queries.  I can't imagine the performance will be anywhere near what it would be if the entities were on the same server/database.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The reason to split across multiple servers is that I want to treat the "orders" or "clients" or whatever else as a stand alone module. In this way if I want to change something in the orders module it won't effect the rest of the app directly.  I understand though the "performance price" I would have to pay.  Maybe the replication is a better solution. I will look into the mule. It looks interesting.

Comment: Would the performance be hit badly if I keep the entities in the same server but different database instances?

Comment: No that would be fine. That will be very performant if you ask me.